# How to Sort a string date array

Tags: swift, string, date, nsmutablearray

I want to sort an array in ascending order. The dates are in string format

```
Optional(["2019-07-08", "2019-07-09", "2019-07-10", "2019-07-11", "2019-07-12", "2019-07-02"])
```

I am trying using below code but it's not working.

```
aryEventTime = aryEventTime.sorted(by: { ($0 as AnyObject).date.compare($1.date) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending })


aryEventTime = aryEventTime.sorted(by: {
            ($0 as AnyObject).date.compare(($1 as AnyObject).date) == .orderedDescending}) as? NSMutableArray
```

Comment: Can't you just do `aryEventTime.sort()`? That should do the job. Your dates are in a format such that sorting lexicographically will result in the same order as sorting in date order.

Comment: Yes, but I am getting error "Value of type '[String]?' has no member 'sort'"

Comment: Please advise me @Sweeper

Comment: Do you know anything about optionals? If not, go learn about them. They are pretty important in Swift. You should do `artEventTime?.sort()`.

Comment: A better question would be why do you have an array of dates as strings instead of an array of actual `Date` instances? You should not work with dates as strings. The only time you should have a date as a string is to display it to the user and it should be shown in a format appropriate to the user's locale.

Answer (score 3):

I would not advise making it a practice doing lexicographic sorting on dates. It's simple enough just to parse these strings to proper `Date` objects and sort on those:

```
let dateStrings = Optional(["2019-07-08", "2019-07-09", "2019-07-10", "2019-07-11", "2019-07-12", "2019-07-02"])

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let sortedDates = dateStrings?.compactMap(formatter.date(from:)).sorted()
```

Comment: Why, dates given in this format will sort perfectly fine as strings.

Comment: For the example strings provided, this is true, but throw in a date from AD 30, e.g. "30-07-08" and lexicographic sort breaks. Though this is contrived, my point is simply that you're making an implicit assumption about your date strings that may not always be true in the future. One of our jobs as developers is to eliminate assumptions or make them explicit.

Comment: Another of our jobs is to not over engineer or over complicate things and find the most suitable solution for the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer:

```
let sortedArray = aryEventTime.sorted { $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending }
```

Comment: This shouldn't work if aryEventTime is optional and looks overly complicated,  why not `aryEventTime?.sort` as mentioned in the comments above or `let sortedArray = aryEventTime?.sorted()`

Comment: This is the hard way. Since your date strings are `yyyy-MM-dd`, you can do: `let sortedArray = aryEventTime.sorted { $0 < $1)` or just `let sortedArray = aryEventTime.sorted()`.

Answer (score 0):

The `array` of `String` that you have is,

```
let arr = ["2019-07-08", "2019-07-09", "2019-07-10", "2019-07-11", "2019-07-12", "2019-07-02"]
```

Instead of converting the `String` to `Date`, you can simply sort this array using `sorted()`, i.e.

```
let sortedArr = arr.sorted()
print(sortedArr)
```

**Output:**

```
["2019-07-02", "2019-07-08", "2019-07-09", "2019-07-10", "2019-07-11", "2019-07-12"]
```

**Note:** `date` `strings` can only be `sorted` without conversion in special cases such as this one. If the `strings` were in the format `yyyy-dd-MM`, for example, then simple `string` `sorting` would not work.

Comment: It should be noted that date strings can only be sorted without conversion in special cases such as this one. If the strings were in the format yyyy-dd-MM, for example, then simple string sorting would not work.